# Как кастомизировать listView в android?

Tags: android, listview

Что бы был такой результат!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В AsyncTask выполняется парсинг страницы.Интересуют данные по свободным велосипедам на станциях в городе,то есть название и количество велосипедов,после чего записывается в ArrayList.
Но записать я могу только в один ArrayList,так как вернуть из doInBackground получается только одну переменную.
Записал я поочередно здесь.

```
while (ilosc.find() && stacja.find()) {
output.add(stacja.group(1));

output.add(ilosc.group());

}
```

То есть в onPostExecute у меня есть одна переменная output,которая содержит нулевым элементом название для первой станции,а первым элементом количество велосипедов для нее.Вторым элементом-название второй станции, третьим количество велосипедов на второй станции..и так далее...

Я так понимаю,что надо как-то сгруппировать каждые 2 элемента.Или даже 3,чтобы добавить еще расстояние между станциями.
Или как иначе добиться результата,такого как на фото?

вот весь код AsynkTask

```
class Parse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {

Document doc;

protected List doInBackground(String... args) {
Element mt = null;
Pattern i = null;
Pattern n = null;
Matcher ilosc = null;
Matcher stacja = null;
List output = new ArrayList<>();
try {
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://kmkbike.pl/panel/station-map/").get();

mt = doc.select("script").last().previousElementSibling();

i = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}");
n = Pattern.compile("(.*)<\\/h3>");
ilosc = i.matcher(mt.html());
stacja = n.matcher(mt.html());



while (ilosc.find() && stacja.find()) {
output.add(stacja.group(1));

output.add(ilosc.group());

}

} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.d(TAG, "OUTPUT");
return output;

}

protected void onPostExecute(List output) {
pd.dismiss();

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
lv.setAdapter((new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, output)));


}
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно использовать RecyclerView и CardView, а не ListView.

Comment: @AdamLuisSean а какая разница?

Comment: @anber почитайте [пост](http://habrahabr.ru/post/237101) на хабре, там очень хорошо написано в чем разница.

Comment: @AdamLuisSean и чем это поможет автору?

Comment: @anber возможно направит на более простой и быстрый способ реализации данной задачи, вместо долгой кастомизации старых виджетов.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно создать модель - класс в котором есть поля:

1. название станции
2. количество велосипедов

И возвращать в `output` List из этих моделей.

Также прийдется использовать кастомный адаптер вместо `ArrayAdapter` У которого убедт переопределен метод `getView()`